# Run a .cmd file through PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I am trying to run a .cmd file on a remote server with PowerShell.

In my .ps1 script I have tried this:

```
C:\MyDirectory\MyCommand.cmd
```

It results in this error:

```
C:\MyDirectory\MyCommand.cmd is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program.
```

And this

```
Invoke-Command C:\MyDirectory\MyCommand.cmd
```

results in this error:

```
Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named
parameters.
```

I do not need to pass any parameters to the PowerShell script. What is the correct syntax that I am looking for?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[`Invoke-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Invoke-Item) will look up the default handler for the file type and tell it to run it.

It's basically the same as double-clicking the file in Explorer, or using `start.exe`.

Comment: That worked great. A further question, is it possible to run the command as administrator through powershell?

Comment: Have a look at the `-Credential` parameter on that cmdlet.

Comment: This has a different effect than simply running `.\MyCommand.cmd` by @GustavoASanchez

Comment: The current script invokes a .cmd file as:
.\Abc.Web.deploy /y
What if I Abc is a variable e.g.
$appName = "Abc"
And then something like:
.\$appName.Web.deploy /y #I know this doesn't work. But what would work here?

Answer (score 15):

Go to C:\MyDirectory and try this:

```
.\MyCommand.cmd
```

Answer (score 14):

Try invoking `cmd /c C:\MyDirectory\MyCommand.cmd` – that should work.

Comment: But how would you use a powershell variable here? What `MyCommand.cmd` was in a string in a variable called `$myCmd`?

Comment: @The Muffin Man: You can build up the command line string for cmd in a PowerShell variable and then pipe it through cmd: `$myCommandLineStr | cmd`. That is the workaround for avoiding the craziness of `Invoke-Item`.

Answer (score 0):

To run or convert batch files to PowerShell (particularly if you wish to sign all your scheduled task scripts with a certificate) I simply create a PowerShell script, for example, deletefolders.ps1.

Input the following into the script:

```
cmd.exe /c "rd /s /q C:\#TEMP\test1"

cmd.exe /c "rd /s /q C:\#TEMP\test2"

cmd.exe /c "rd /s /q C:\#TEMP\test3"
```

*Each command needs to be put on a new line, calling cmd.exe again.

This script can now be signed and run from PowerShell outputting the commands to command prompt / cmd directly.

It is a much safer way than running batch files!

Answer (score 0):

First you can reach till that folder:
cd 'C:\MyDirectory'
and then use:
./MyCommand.cmd