# Run bat file via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a batch file from remote computer but it also doesn't work locally

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteComputer -ScriptBlock {
    Start-Process  "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\version\Installer\Installer.bat" -NoNewWindow -Wait
} -Credential $credentials -ErrorAction Stop
```

There is no errors but nothing happens
The installer.bat is located under C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\version\Installer
The batch file contain setup.exe that also located at the same folder.
I am searching for hours the solution

For local I used this:

```
Start-Process "cmd.exe"  "/c C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\version\Installer\Installer.bat" -NoNewWindow
```

Seems that its working locally when i am going to the right folder (cd c:..)
and run

```
Invoke-Expression -Command 'cmd.exe /C C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\version\Installer\Installer.bat'
```

So how can i do it remotely (I mean to go to the right path first)

Comment: Have you tried Invoke-Item on the batch file, from inside your Invoke-Command? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423424/run-a-cmd-file-through-powershell

Comment: I changed the bat file to start from the right folder and its working locally 
Invoke-Expression -Command 'cmd.exe /C C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\version\Installer\Installer.bat'

But remotely its not

try {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteComputer -Credential $credentials -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock  {
    Invoke-Expression -Command 'cmd.exe /C C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\version\Installer\Installer.bat'
        #Start-Process "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\8.6.22.607.3_GA\Installer\Installer.bat"
    }
} 
catch {
    Write-Host "error"
}

Comment: When you try the Invoke-Expression version without the try/catch, does it now throw any errors messages?

Comment: No error . I don’t know what I can do else

Comment: Decided to take another look at this, and I'm wondering - are you copying the batch file to the remote system?  The path you are showing is a local path, so when the scriptblock runs on the remote machine, it needs that batch file at that location locally on that remote machine.

Comment: Yes the batch was copied to the remote machine