# Npm doesn't work in PowerShell after NodeJs installation

Tags: node.js, database, npm

After NodeJs Installation (windows 11) , when i write  "node -v" in CMD and PowerShell , it shows node version but when i write "npm -v" it causes problem

for NPM when i write "npm -v" in powershell it shows "npm word not recognized"
when i write it in CMD , it shows below

**C:\Users\HP>npm -v
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
8.19.2**

i have tried many things ( **different versions, install by NVM , environment variable set**) but my **powershell** isn't recognizing "npm"
and that's why i am not able to work in VScode

what to do ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run a .cmd file through PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423424/run-a-cmd-file-through-powershell)

Comment: [Check ComSpec environemnt variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42667234/125562)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a try with

- restart the system
- check the PATH details or configure the Base path which NPM exists
  (Ex: C:\Program Files\nodejs), if ENV path has many variables, check
  for the separator ';'.
- Can try with the base path (Ex: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm -v)

Comment: I have tried all, but this doesn't work.
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42508090/npm-command-return-message-g-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-comm?rq=1" , i have tried the things written here also

Answer (score 0):

npm is a batch file.
It not directly executable.
Use CMD program to execute it.
The easiest way to do so is to use [Invoke-Item command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423424/run-a-cmd-file-through-powershell).